# How to set jQuery UI tab to vertical?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

i am using jQuery Ui Tab : http://jqueryui.com/tabs/

but i want to set Tab like this, how could i do it?

[image]

`what i tired is`  : http://jsfiddle.net/s766A/

Comment: I would start here http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#vertical , but if you want to rotate the text you will need css3 transforms for the rotation.

Comment: .rotation-text {
    -moz-transform:rotate(-270deg); 
    -moz-transform-origin: bottom left;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-270deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: bottom left;
    -o-transform: rotate(-270deg);
    -o-transform-origin:  bottom left;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=1);
}

Answer (score 0):

```
use this css 
<style>
.ui-tabs-vertical { width: 55em; }
.ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav { padding: .2em .1em .2em .2em; float: left; width: 12em; }
.ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav li { clear: left; width: 100%; border-bottom-width: 1px !important; border-right-width: 0 !important; margin: 0 -1px .2em 0; }
.ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav li a { display:block; }
.ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-active { padding-bottom: 0; padding-right: .1em; border-right-width: 1px; border-right-width: 1px; }
.ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-panel { padding: 1em; float: right; width: 40em;}
</style>
```

Comment: Still have horizonal text. I found similiar example here: http://keith-wood.name/uiTabs.html.

Comment: you don't understand my question, i don't need horizonal text :D

Comment: this is not horizontal text. this css will set the tabs from top to left.  check the demos at http://jqueryui.com/tabs/

Comment: if you want it on right then just modify the css. see this http://jsfiddle.net/s766A/1/